# Python speech recognition error - Invalid number of channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

I'm running a speech recognition code on python as part of a project. I'm facing a really odd kind of a problem 
When I put the speech recognition code inside a function like:

```
def loop():
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=2) as source:
            print("say something")
            audio = r.listen(source)
            try:
                    print("you said "+r.recognize_google(audio))
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                    print("Could not understand")
            except sr.RequestError as e:
                    print("errpr: {0}".format(e))
```

It gives me the following error:

> with sr.Microphone(device_index=2) as source:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/speech_recognition/**init**.py",
>   line 141, in **enter**
>       input=True,  # stream is an input stream   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
>       stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in
>   **init**
>       self._stream = pa.open(**arguments) OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels

But if I run the same lines of code outside the function like not inside the `def loop():` it runs properly

What should I do?
My python version is 3.5.4

Comment: removing the device_index made it work for me `with sr.Microphone() as source:`

Comment: It works without error but it gets stuck at `r.listen(audio)` for which I couldn't find solutions that worked

Comment: you have to speak something at the "say something" prompt or else it will be stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that way:

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone(device_index=2)

def loop():
    with m as source:
        print("say something")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            print("you said "+r.recognize_google(audio))
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Could not understand")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("errpr: {0}".format(e))

loop()
```

Don't create multiple `Microphone()` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Is access to the channel exclusive?  Can only one thread hold access to the microphone?  Your problem might be that you are trying to access the microphone multiple times concurrently (multiple loop calls) rather than just access it once (outside of loop).

Comment: I see...so how can I fix it? because this error occurs only when I pass the "device_index=2" parameter.Without the parameter the error isn't there, but that causes a new set of problems like it gets stuck at `r.listen(audio)`