# recording algo : OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels in pyaudio

Tags: python, audio-recording, pyaudio

I am trying to run a simple recording algo in python with pyaudio but i have the ERROR :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "save_audio.py", line 19, in <module>
    input=True)
  File "/Users/sacharobberse/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sacharobberse/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels
```

Here is my code :

```
import pyaudio
import wave

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16

CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
CHUNK = int(RATE / 10)
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE, input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print ("recording...")
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print ("finished recording")


# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()



file = open("newfile.raw", "w")
file.write(b''.join(frames))
file.close()
```

I am new to programming and can't figure it out.
I am on a Mac
Thanks

Comment: Also asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952667/python-speech-recognition-error-invalid-number-of-channels