# Python SpeechRecognition - OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio, pocketsphinx

I've been programming for several years but am quite new to Python, I'm implenting some speech recognition on a Raspberry Pi using https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/ and streaming the microphone output direction to Wit.ai.

I've been using PocketSphinx to constantly listen for the "wake word" and on my ubuntu VM the code below is working fine

```
class Recognition:
    def detection(self):
        speech = LiveSpeech(lm=False, keyphrase='alexa', kws_threshold=1e-20)

        print('Listening for wake word.');

        for phrase in speech:
            return self.start()

    def start(self):
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

        print('Heard wake word, listening and streaming audio.')

        with sr.Microphone(device_index=2) as source:
            audio = recognizer.listen(source)
        try:
            content = recognizer.recognize_wit(audio, key=WIT_AI_KEY)

            print(content)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Unable to understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Error from Wit.ai: {}".format(e))


Recognition().detection()
```

But when running it on my Raspberry Pi, once the "wake word" has been triggered I'm getting the following error from PyAudio:
`OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels`

If I run `Recognition.start()` directly it seems to be working absolutely fine as long as I remove the `device_index` from the `Microphone()`?

Does anyone know what the cause of this might be? As if I remove `device_index` and still run `Recognition().detection()` from the start I get a `IOError: No Default Input Device Available`

Just to note, when recording via `arecord` on my Raspberry Pi, the audio input/microphone seems to be recording absolutely fine.

Comment: You don't have a default device input.

Comment: @Xilpex I've set up my `/etc/asound.conf` file to what I assume is working with `arecord`?

Comment: Main question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952667/python-speech-recognition-error-invalid-number-of-channels

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this in the future, it seems to be an issue with using `LiveSpeech` and `SpeechRecognition` python modules and them having their own `PyAudio` instances.

I've had to change the code to initialise my own `PyAudio` instance and then use the `Decoder` sent with `PocketSphinx` for the wake word and then directly continue the same `stream` directly to `requests` for Wit.ai.